# Meta questions missing required tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

There's an even dozen [older posts on Meta Super User that lack any of the required tags](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=-%5Bdiscussion%5D%20-%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bsupport%5D%20-%5Bfeature-request%5D%20is%3Aquestion) (i.e., [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request),[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), or [support](/questions/tagged/support)).

It used to be that Moderators could post questions without one of the required tags. Plus old questions migrated to Meta would also lack them. But that loophole has been closed.

In case, you know, anyone was interested in cleaning them up...

(I can't. Not enough rep to edit in Meta.)

Comment: seems like most were  mass migrated from [metase]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They've been cleaned up now, all are properly tagged. Thanks for letting us know.